# Filter collection with dropdown attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, php, mysql, collection, zend-framework

I want to hide products on frontend that have attribute brand = `branda` and `brandb`. Attributes are dropdown and flat tables are enabled.
Reason is i am importing alot of products and some of those should be hidden automatically.

My plan is to hide with event `<catalog_product_collection_load_before>`.

In observer method i have this:

```
public function filterProductsbyBrand($observer) {
                $AttributeName = 'brand';
                $brand = 'branda';
                $brand2 = 'brandb';
                if (!Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin()) {
                    if (isset($observer['collection'])) {
                        $collection = $observer['collection'];
                        $collection->addFieldToFilter($AttributeName, array('neq' => Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttribute($AttributeName)->getSource()->getOptionId($brand)))
                        $collection->addFieldToFilter($AttributeName, array('neq' => Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttribute($AttributeName)->getSource()->getOptionId($brand2)));
                        return $this;
                    }
                }
            }
```

But this give error and are not working. Error are like this:

```
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.brand' in 'where clause'' in /var/www/mysite.com/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
```

If i run external with this i get correct collection.

```
$AttributeName = 'brand';
$brand = 'branda';
$brand2 = 'brandb';
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addFieldToFilter($AttributeName, array('neq' => Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttribute($AttributeName)->getSource()->getOptionId($brand)))
    ->addFieldToFilter($AttributeName, array('neq' => Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttribute($AttributeName)->getSource()->getOptionId($brand2)));
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this.

If you are able to filter before, don't filter in frontend. Makes everything slower and harder to maintain.

Fix your import and disable/hide them with visibility.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your observer file

```
public function filterProductsbyBrand(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $collection = $observer->getCollection();
    $attributeName = 'brand';
    $brand1 = 'branda';
    $brand2 = 'brandb';
    if (!Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin() && $collection->getSize()) {
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('brand')
            ->addFieldToFilter($attributeName, array('neq' => Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttribute($attributeName)->getSource()->getOptionId($brand1)))
            ->addFieldToFilter($attributeName, array('neq' => Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttribute($attributeName)->getSource()->getOptionId($brand2)));
        return $this;
    }
}
```